# How to calculate the error bars for a small data set with no information about the underling distributions

Tags: statistics

I have a data set of an experiment with two groups - A and B.
I have 4 objects in each group, a total of 8 objects.
I am making a measurement of each object, and get a rational number larger then zero.
I do not have information about the underling distributions of the data in each group.
The measurements are independent.

I would like to calculate the coefficient of variation of each group, and get an estimate of the confidence interval for the CV. Given that I have a small data set and no information about the underling distribution, is this possible? If so, how?

What I tried:
I thought about bootstrapping, but for such a small sample I think I will not get a good representation of the true distribution of the CV. Is this true?